# Why LIME does not show prediction probability for the other class?

Tags: probability, python, lime

[image: Lime explanatition as example]

On the picture above you can see prediction probabilities. In this case it shows 100% poisonous. However, on next two figures it shows that there is actually small probability of other class (with feature gill_size, blue-colored). What is the reason behind this inconsistency?

Picture from http://pythondata.com/local-interpretable-model-agnostic-explanations-lime-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. The first (*left-most*) numbers reflect the predictions of the classifier used (here this classifier is a random forest (*)). The second (*central*) numbers reflect the *average* influence of that particular feature value in the final predictions. These two sets of numbers should indeed convey similar information but they do not need to be exactly the same.

In particular, the first numbers come from our (potentially highly sophisticated)  full model that encapsulates the associations across all the features in our training sample. The second numbers encapsulate the behaviour of the linear model used by LIME in the neighbourhood of the sample-point we trying to explain. (Notice that LIME usually does not employ all the available features when making an explanation, we usually set the `num_features` to be smaller than the total number of available features.)
For the example shown, the predicted probability of *that particular mushroom* being poisonous is $1$. The second numbers suggest that, given the training data available, having `odor=foul` would increase *on average* the predicted probability of that mushroom being poisonous by $0.26$ and similarly, having `gill-size=broad` would decrease *on average* the predicted probability by $0.13$. 
That does not necessitate that the overall predicted probability from the full classifier is the sum of these *average* changes - thus there is no inconsistency. :)

(*)While the blog-post link provided does not show the source of that image, the full notebook where this picture is taken from, can be found [here](https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial%20-%20continuous%20and%20categorical%20features.html). This how I know that the underlying full model is an RF.

Comment: BTW, welcome to the CV community!

Comment: Hi @user11852. Very useful explanation. I have a question though. If all those 2nd number doesn't add up to the total probability, can I know what do they add up to? We don't see the intercept here. So, it is possible that for a class 1, we can still get lot of negative numbers (feature with negative influence in 2nd diagram). However, with high intercept, that class still became positive. How do you interpret Lime in that case?

Comment: Assuming we use logistic regression as the underlying explainer we would interpret LIME  coefficient as affecting the log-odds. (I saw your question I will try to answer it tonight or tomorrow night)